# ASP.NET MVC vNext VS2015 RC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working with VS2015 and ASP.NET vNext, i'm got stuck on the following two scenarios.

1. trying to add a reference class library (csproj) to a asp.net vNext class library (xproj) in the same solution.
2. trying to add framework 4.0 or 4.5 compiled dll added into xproj.

Is it possible at all to add references to xproj?

Comment: You should rename your question title making it more explanatory. However, with asp.net beta 4 and VS2015 RC they had  re-introduced the possibility to reference an entire project (but I'm not sure you can do it with a csproj).

Answer (score 1):

We add the csproj into the xproj with out using the dnu command by using the ass reference command in solution explorer.Once we add the csproj into the xproj it automatically wrap the project compatible into the xproj(like what happend when using the dnu command).